# logrotate weekly archiving empties out daily files

Tags: cron, logging, logrotate

My aim is to maintain 4 days' worth of log files so that on the fifth day, a zip file with all four log files is created. The four log files created so far are deleted.

This is my `logrotate.conf`:

```
/home/ubuntu/logs/server.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 5
    compress
    create
    dateext
    dateyesterday
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
    extension .gz
}
```

I have a `crontab` entry as:

```
2 0 * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /home/ubuntu/logrotate.conf --state /home/ubuntu/logrotate.state
```

I see a zip file for the fifth day along with empty files of previous four days and four more zip files of the empty files.

Isn't `rotate 5` and `compress` supposed to mean that, remove previous 4 files after compressing them into one archive and zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotate` and `compress` are independent. `compress` compresses each rotated log file, `rotate` sets how many rotated log files to keep. Using them together does not mean that rotated log files are combined and compressed.

What you could do is use a `post-rotate` script like so:

```
zcat /home/ubuntu/logs/server.log.*.gz |
  gzip | sponge /home/ubuntu/logs/server.log.$(date -d "now - 5 days" +%Y-%m-%d).gz
```

(Using `sponge` from `moreutils` to overwrite the last log file)

That said, `extension .gz` is useless unless your log files actually have a `.gz` extension.

Comment: And, the `crontab` entry still points to a daily job?

Comment: @cogitoergosum assuming you still want the log file rotated daily, yes.

Comment: I will accept your answer. However, after much thought, I have a different requirement. And, my attempt for that one didn't work either. :( If you won't mind, can you please suggest? 
https://askubuntu.com/q/1012123/203989